# Linear combination of functions and their Wronskian.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, wronskian

Let $u_1(t), \cdots, u_n(t)$ defined on $\mathbb R$ and let  $W(t:u_1, u_2, \cdots, u_n)$ stand for Wronskian $\begin{vmatrix}
u_1(t) & \cdots & u_n(t) \\
u_1'(t) & \cdots & u_n'(t) \\
\vdots &  & \vdots \\
u_1^{(n-1)} (t)& \cdots & u_n^{(n-1)} (t)
\end{vmatrix}$.

Suppose $W(t: u_1, \cdots, u_n)\neq 0.$

If $n-1$ times differentiable function $v(t)$ satisfies $v^{(k)}(t)=c_1u_1^{(k)}(t)+\cdots + c_nu_n^{(k)}(t)$ for $k=0,1,\cdots, n-1$, then prove that $c_i=\dfrac{W(t:u_1, \cdots, u_{i-1}, v, u_{i+1},   \cdots, u_n)}{W(t:u_1, \cdots, u_n)} \ (i=1, \cdots, n)$

I could calculate this in the easier case $n=2$, but I don't know what I have to do in the case of $n$.

How can I calculate $c_i$ ?

Comment: This looks like an application of Cramer's rule for solving linear systems https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule